# FFMPEG and RTMPDUMP is unable to play content from Red5 server

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, red5

I am using Red5 1.0.7-RELEASE(ubuntu 12.04) to understand the rtmp protocol. I tried "Publisher" demo to see the functioning. Live publish and play works fine in the "Publisher" demo page. But when I publish from demo page and play through FFMPEG: **avplay rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/stream** or 
RTMPDUMP: **rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/stream" -o - | "vlc"** I see some problem. Only after I end publishing I see data in the FFMPEG or RTMPDUMP.

In case of rtmpt, VLC says unable to open MRL when I can able to play data in Publisher demo page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing in VLC, use their built-in RTMP handling and also be aware that VLC may still not support some codecs in FLV such as Speex. Lastly, you normally have to tell rtmpdump that a stream is 'live' or it might assume and request vod, if I'm not mistaken.